# What is the most appropriate place to ask for help when the question involves code, combinatorics and CSTheory?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would need help to implement in Python an algorithm called [DXZ](https://aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI17/paper/view/14907/13855). It is similar to Donald Knuth's [DLX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) algorithm (Dancing Links) with the exception that is uses a [ZDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-suppressed_decision_diagram) (Zero Suppressed Decision Diagram) to perform the search.

I already have my own implementation of DLX and found a ZDD implemention on GitHub but I am unable to combine both. I would like to reach people that:

- have some understanding of combinatorics
- can make sense of the research paper (linked above)
- are proficient in Python

Given this situation, what would the best place to ask for help ? (if StackExchange, where exactly?)

Is the Stack platform the right place to go for this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you need multiple questions for this. Trying to tackle it all in one question may not get you the answers you want.

The theory should be on topic on [CS Theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/). I would sort your questions about the paper there.

Once sorted, when you run into specific Python questions, ask those on SO. Then you can reference the theory questions as background.